# Python で引数の型を判別したい

Tags: python

関数 typecheck() でやりたいのは引数 v が class なのか function なのか それ以外なのかの判別することです。
現状では文字列比較していますが、この比較判別部分について、もっと正しいやり方があれば教えてください。よろしくお願いします。

```
class C:
    pass
def typecheck(v):
    if   str(v).startswith('<class'):
          return("class")
    elif str(v).startswith('<function'):
          return("function")
    else: return("other")
print( typecheck(C) )
print( typecheck(typecheck) )
print( typecheck("") )
```

Answer (score 3):

基本的にはこちらのようなコードになると思います。必要に応じて細部を調整してください。

```python
import types

class C:
    pass
def typecheck(v):
    if   isinstance(v, type):
          return "class"
    elif isinstance(v, types.FunctionType):
          return "function"
    else: return "other"
print( typecheck(C) )
print( typecheck(typecheck) )
print( typecheck("") )
```